# Unable to add elements in NSmutableArray more than 260 elements from my for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Here is the code. We are unable to get complete array elements. It's restricting to 260 elements but there are 360 elements.

```
-(void)scheduleCal{
    float monthlyPayment = 0.0; //monthly Payment
    float loanAmount = 100000; //Loan Amount
    int years = 30;
    float intRate = 6;
    float i = intRate / 1200;
    int n = years * 12;// 360
    float rPower = pow(1+i, n);

    float mPayment = loanAmount*((i*(pow((1+i), n)))/((pow(1+i, n))-1));

    monthlyPayment = loanAmount * i * rPower / (rPower -1);

    NSLog(@"Monthly Payment:%0.2f %f",mPayment,round(monthlyPayment));

    float tempLoanAmount = loanAmount;

    self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int r = 1; r <= n; r++) {
        float interestPayment = tempLoanAmount *i;
        double principalPayment = mPayment - interestPayment;

        tempLoanAmount -= principalPayment;

        NSDictionary *dic = @{@"sno":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",r],@"principal": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",principalPayment],@"interest":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",interestPayment],@"balance":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",tempLoanAmount]};

        [self.array addObject:dic];
        dic = nil;
    }

    NSLog(@"Array:%@ %ld",self.array,(unsigned long)self.array.count);
}
```

Comment: Print  dic check it is nil or not

Comment: I got this Log for last 3 objects. {
        balance = "47090.23";
        interest = "237.26";
        principal = "362.29";
        sno = 260;
    },
        {
        balance = "46726.13";
        interest = "235.45";
        principal = "364.10";
        sno = 261;
    },
        {
        balance = "46360.21";
        interest = "233.63";
        principal = "365.92";
        sno = 262;
    },
        {
        balance = "45992.46";
        interest = "231.80";
        principal = "367.75";
        sno = 263

Comment: Because it is not possible until dic is nil, You have for loop which is looping till 360 that's has no any issue

Comment: @vinukondapraveen : From the logs looks like its clipped of from console. That does not mean Array had only 263 objects. Print the count of array. If its 360 that means there are 360 elements in it

Comment: @SandeepBhandari : I have printed it shows like this <decode: missing data>

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya : Dictionary is printing correctly without nil, but afte some amount dic not added to array.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari : Thanks, it worked, yes console cliped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong in the code. Code is perfectly fine. Array contains 360 elements. It's just got clipped on console. If you need to check or print the entire contents on console use any of the below way.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.array) {
     NSLog(@"Dict: %@ ",dict);
}

OR

printf("%s", [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", array].UTF8String);
```